# converting BASH to Python (v2.6)

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts

I have this code in bash and do not know how to translate the lines with 'ps -C.....' and ' ps -eo....' any help in how to write these lines?

```
if [ "$SwapUsedActivity" == "true" ]
then 
    echo "WARNING: Potential Swapping happening please check for increasing swap usage"
    echo "INFO: checking kswapd number of process and cputime, check for TIME colume for how busy kswapd was"
    ps -C kswapd0 -C kswapd1 -C kswapd2 -C kswapd3 -C kswapd4  -o pid,ppid,stime,etime,time,pcpu,args
else
    echo "INFO: High swap space usage detected, not a potential issue but check activity"
fi
else
    echo "INFO: Swap usage within the limits"
fi
if [ $AvgAnnonymousMemoryused -gt 20 ]
then 
    echo "INFO: High residential memory usage detected, this may not be an issue, please check top memory consuming processes"
    echo "INFO: Printing top 10 memory consuming processes"
    ps -eo pid,ppid,user,rss,comm --sort=rss | tail -10 
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `subprocess` module :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess
command_1 = 'ps -eo pid,ppid,user,rss,comm --sort=rss'.split()
command_2 = 'tail -10'.split()
first = subprocess.Popen(command_1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.call(command_2, stdin=first.stdout)
```

- `command_1` is the command on the left of the pipe, split on spaces to make a list which is required by `subprocess.Popen` class
- `command_2` is the command on the left of the pipe split similarly to `command_1`
- `first` is an object of the `subprocess.Popen` class, `subprocess.Popen` executes the `command_1` and send its STDOUT to `PIPE` so that we can use it as an input to `command_2`
- `subprocess.call` will execute the `command_2` with its STDIN coming from the STDOUT of `first`

For `ps -C kswapd0 -C kswapd1 -C kswapd2 -C kswapd3 -C kswapd4  -o pid,ppid,stime,etime,time,pcpu,args` command you can do :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess
command = 'ps -C kswapd0 -C kswapd1 -C kswapd2 -C kswapd3 -C kswapd4  -o pid,ppid,stime,etime,time,pcpu,args'.split()
subprocess.call(command)
```

Read the [official documentation on subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to get more idea.

Comment: ive tried subprocess before and have run into errors because I am working in version 2.6, will this work in 2.6?

Comment: @ShuKaibutsu According to documentation https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html, it should....

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) to grab the data programmatically.

That's going to take a little while to learn so the quicker, scrappier alternative is to [run the commands through a subshell-style construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266901/12870) from Python.

```
import commands
exit_code, output = commands.getstatusoutput('ps -eo pid,ppid,user,rss,comm --sort=rss')
print '\n'.join(output.split('\n')[-10:])
```

I've moved the `tail` into pure Python there, just for fun.